# Formula or script to replace space with non-breaking space &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am concat'ing several cells together to produce an HTTP POST url, the problem I am running into is where there is intended white space in an entry such as "San Antonio". The issue it is causing is that it breaks the link in the final cell.

I have been searching for hours and while I did find a great piece of JS:
`str = str.replace(/\s/g, "&nbsp;");`
Unfortunately I don't know how to use JS in Google Apps Script or how I would specify what cell.

The developers at Sheets fixes this just fine as the links within sheets load perfectly, the problem I face is that I need to send the data out using the actual cell value.

Comment: _"I don't know how to use JS in Google Apps Script or how I would specify what cell"_ - That should be part of the documentation

Comment: I believe, if you're talking about URL, [you need](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) to replace spaces with either `+` or `%20`.

Comment: I am very open to using %20, it's the formula itself I can not figure out. I have tried the TRIM function dozens of ways with no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a formula to replace all space with `%20`, then you could use this in cell `B2`:

```
=arrayformula(if(A2:A<>"",regexreplace(A2:A,"\ ","%20"),))
```

The `arrayformula` works down the sheet.

[image]

Comment: Your solution worked great. Thank you Aresvik. 
What I had done was this `=SUBSTITUTE(AK5,CHAR(32),"%20")` it just didn't feel as clean as I thought it should have.